# What does a Software Development (or Software Engineer) in Test do?

Tags: automated-testing, career-development

I applied for a job at google which is Test Analyst - I thought it would fit me due to the description of the job. Then I got a call and they are looking more of a software engineering in test. Now this brought me to a question to myself and my fellow QAs:

1. What is Software Engineer in Test?
2. I am currently doing automation - selenium and C#. This may still mean I am not a software engineer? I may do coding but now I came to realize I am just automating the manual test cases. Are there other uses of automation aside from just automating the manual test cases or am I just not on the right track?

Comment: read all about it in the Google testing blog
https://testing.googleblog.com/

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/25136/8992

Comment: I think google is looking for a white box tester who have more knowledge on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the exact job description, my personal opinion is:

[image]

A software engineer in test is more likely coming from a software engineering background but develops into a tester later on. They are more of a coder than a tester.

I am not saying a tester is necessarily a less-good coder but it is a general perception.

I suspected that your past working experience did not fit Google's job description; they were looking for someone with more programming experience than you do now.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you reading answers to a similar question: [What is the difference between Software Test Engineer, Test Automation Engineer and Software Developer in Test (SDET)?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6408/what-is-the-difference-between-software-test-engineer-test-automation-engineer)

Here would like to answer in detail to the following part of your question:

> Are there other uses of automation aside from just automating the manual test cases or am I just not on the right track?

Yes, there are. I recommend you reading ["A Context-Driven Approach to
Automation in Testing"](http://www.satisfice.com/articles/cdt-automation.pdf) of James Bach and Michael Bolton. Part of that is covered also in the James Bach presentation ["Agile Test Automation"](http://www.satisfice.com/presentations/agileauto.pdf):

> - **Test generation (data and script generators).** Tools might create specialized data such as randomized email messages, or populate
>     databases, or generate combinations of parameters that we’d like to
>     cover with our tests.
> - **System configuration.** Tools might preserve or reproduce system parameters, set systems to a particular state, or create or restore
>     “ghosted” disk drives.
> - **Simulators.** Tools might simulate sub-systems or environmental conditions that are not available (or not yet available) for testing,
>     or are too expensive to provide live on demand.
> - **Test execution (harnesses and test scripts).** Tools might
>     operate the software itself, either simulating a user working through
>     the GUI, or bypassing the GUI and using an alternative testable
>     interface.
> - **Probes.** Tools might make visible what would otherwise be
>     invisible to humans. They might statically analyze a product, parse a
>     log file, or monitor system parameters.
> - **Oracles.** An oracle is any mechanism by which we detect failure
>     or success. Tools might automatically detect certain kinds of error
>     conditions in a product.
> - **Activity recording & coverage analysis.** Tools might watch
>     testing as it happens and retrospectively report what was and was not
>     tested. They might record actions for later replay in other tests.
> - **Test management.** Tools might record test results; organize test
>     ideas or metrics.